# Special character in the parameter of Read action method of Html.Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Master Detailed Html Kendo Grid where Master grid is set its model Id with the primary key column. This primary key column may have a special character e.g. A&12345. On Master Grid row expand event, Detail grid data load call is sent like

```
    $(gridName).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

and Read action of Html kendo grid is as follow

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetGridData", "GridController", new { filterParameter = "#=filterParameterValue#" }))
```

in above read action the filterParameterValue contains that special character which is mentioned above i-e.

> A&12345

Now in network traffic i can see A&12345 is being passed but when i look into the controller action method, it is showing me only A in the parameter value and everything else is getting truncated.

Following is my from the Network

/GridController/GetGridData?filterParameter=A&12345 HTTP    POST    200 application/json    0.64 KB 55.50 s XMLHttpRequest  10108   0   16  55490   0   676295

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. Any advice will really be appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, tell me, what you want your filterParameter to be ? because as i can see you are posting a whole xml request and i suppose that you don't want that. 
So i suggest you look at filterParameterValue to see what you have in it and why.

Comment: i want A&12345 to be passed to my controller action method

Comment: i know it is treated as a reserve word but what is the solution? Also, it is not only about "&" it could be any other special character as well. I need some fool proof solution so that all special characters can be passed to the controller action method.

Answer (score 3):

Just try to execute escape function inside template tags:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetGridData", "GridController", new { filterParameter = "#=escape(filterParameterValue)#" }))
```

Comment: This fixed my problem! It should be marked as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Kindly include also the escape function.

Comment: Please provide the code for escape function. I does not work for me. I also tried using encodeURIComponent but that does not work either.

Comment: Guys, escape is JS global function. If this is not working - try encodeURI instead since escape is deprecated for some time. If you have trouble with both so maybe something prevents accessing the global context.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the "&" character is understood by the browser as if you passed another variable. He understand something like that :

/GridController/GetGridData?filterParameter=A&MyData=toto

So you will need to encode the value.

Try that :

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetGridData", "GridController", new { filterParameter = Uri.EscapeDataString("#=filterParameterValue#") }))
```

I'm not sure if it's the rigth escape method, i haven't tested that piece of code.

Comment: it is not doing the job. I am getting %23%3filterParameterValue%23 posted back to the controller action method

Comment: ha yeah... my bad... you need to escape the value inside filterParameterValue but it's javascript... i'm sorry, i don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by encoding the value in my controller before passing my model to the view like as follow

```
System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(model.FilterParameterValue))
```

I have created an additional property in my model which will be responsible of carrying this encoded value and on view post in my controller action methods, I am decoding it back like as follow

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(model.FilterParameterValue))
```